# getting the values of an Enum type in the web interface

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented an enum class.This is the code:

```
  public enum OfferType {
     NO_OFFER("Pas d'offre", "N/A"),
     LOCAL("Offre locale", "LOCAL"),
     NATIONAL("Offre nationale", "NATIONAL"),
     DEFAULT("DEFAULT", "DEFAULT");

     // private static Logger logger =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(OfferType.class);
       public final String frontLabel;

       public final String daoField;

     OfferType(String frontLabel, String daoField) {
         this.frontLabel = frontLabel;
         this.daoField = daoField;
}

      public static OfferType getEnum(String daoField) {
          if (NO_OFFER.daoField.equals(daoField)){
            return NO_OFFER;
    }
         if (LOCAL.daoField.equals(daoField)){
             return LOCAL;
    }
         if (NATIONAL.daoField.equals(daoField)){
             return  NATIONAL;
    }

      //logger.error("Unknown enum value: " + daoField);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Enum specified for this    string:"+daoField);

  }
}
```

I have a class Order defined with an attribute with the type "OfferType".
I should instantiate an object "order" and set this property to the object, like the following:

```
order.setOfferType(OfferType.getEnum((rs.getString("offerType"))));
```

The problem is that with this setting I will have the value with uppercase of the enum.I want to retrieve the first value of the enum instead.How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses default jackson serializer. Thus in order to have custom serialization you should annotate your field:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = OfferTypeSerializer.class)
private OfferType offerType;
```

and create `OfferTypeSerializer.class`:

```
public class OfferTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OfferType> {

     @Override
     public void serialize(OrderType value, JsonGenerator jgen,
         SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         jgen.writeString(value.frontLabel);
     }
 }
```

Another way is to get value calling `offerType.frontLabel` and setting it as `String` or implementing `toString()` method which is not the best solution:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.frontLabel;
}
```

If you're calling `getEnum(String daoField)` to get data you should write it in the next form:

```
  public static String getEnumFrontLabel(String daoField) {
      if (NO_OFFER.daoField.equals(daoField)){
        return NO_OFFER.frontLabel;
}
     if (LOCAL.daoField.equals(daoField)){
         return LOCAL.frontLabel;
}
     if (NATIONAL.daoField.equals(daoField)){
         return  NATIONAL.frontLabel;
}
```

And actually better to use next form of returning enum:

```
public static String getEnumFrontLabel(String daoField) {
    OfferType t = getType(field);
    if (t != null) {
         return t.frontLabel;
    }
    return null;

} 
public static OfferType getType(String field) {
    for (OfferType type : values()) {
        if (type.equals(field)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I did'nt use serialization to pass data tu UI.I have an abstractOrderRepository Class where I declared a Map row function that returns an object order like this:

Comment: I added the full code below.It is now more explicit

Comment: what type of json serializer are you using? private OfferType offerType; in Order class is serialized by type. E.g. If you use faster xml you can add @JsonDeserialize/@JsonSerialize annotations. If it is jaxb you can add @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. Please investigate your pom or lib folder and tell if you have smth named "jackson", "fasterxml", "moxy"

Comment: I have just investigated in my pom, but I didn't find any of the names that you have mentionned.What I need is to retrieve the first values(which are Strings), but the object should be set as i have shown in the code(with the enum types).This is what confuses me.